# Understanding Direct product of subgroups in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap, direct-product

I am trying to obtain a direct product in GAP, but I am not able to understand the output. The ploblem is the following, I have a GL(2,3) group of 48 elements ($2\times 2$) matrices, and I want to make the direct product between two of its subgroups, lets say $C_2 \times D_8$.

Here the elements in $C_2$ are:

```
cg2: [ [ [ -1, 0 ], [ 0, -1 ] ], [ [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1 ] ] ]
```

and the elements in $D_8$

```
gd8: [ [ [ -1, 0 ], [ 0, -1 ] ], [ [ 0, -E(4) ], [ -E(4), 0 ] ], 
    [ [ 0, E(4) ], [ E(4), 0 ] ], [ [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1 ] ], 
    [ [ -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ], 
      [ 1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ] ], 
    [ [ -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, 1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ], 
      [ -1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ] ], 
   [ [ 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ], 
      [ 1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ] ], 
   [[ 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, 1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ], 
      [ -1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ] ] ]
```

and the direct product:

```
dp:=DirectProduct(gc2,gd8);
 <matrix group of size 16 with 4 generators>

    Elements(dp);
    [ [ [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, -1]], 
    [ [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, -1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ] ], 
    [ [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0 ] ],
    [ [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ], 
    [ [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], 
       [ 0, 0, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ], 
       [ 0, 0, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ] ], 
    [ [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, 
      1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ], [ 0, 0, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, 
      1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ] ], 
    [ [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], 
      [ 0, 0, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ], 
      [ 0, 0, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ] ], 
   [ [ -1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0 ], 
      [ 0, 0, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ], 
      [ 0, 0, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ] ], 
   [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, -1 ] ], 
   [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, -1 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ] ], 
   [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0 ] ], 
   [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1 ] ], 
   [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], 
     [ 0, 0, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ], 
     [ 0, 0, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ] ], 
   [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], 
     [ 0, 0, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ], 
     [ 0, 0, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ] ], 
   [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], 
     [ 0, 0, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ], 
     [ 0, 0, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3, -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ] ], 
   [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, 
     1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3 ],[ 0, 0, 1/2*E(8)-1/2*E(8)^3, 
     -1/2*E(8)+1/2*E(8)^3 ] ] ]
```

So, in this point, I am no able to understand these $4\times 4$ matrices output. I know $C_2$ is a normal subgroup of GL(2,3) and $D_8$ is a non abelian group, but the result confuses me. Does anybody has a clue?.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, it is not completely clear to me what you are trying to do and where you are confused. Is it the `E(8)` in the output of the $4 \times 4$ matrices?

Comment: @fourier1234 Thank for your answer. I am trying to make a direct product between 2 of the subgroups of GL(2,3), a normal subgroup and a non abelian subgroup. Yes `E(8)` is in the output of the $4\times 4$ matrices. I was expecting a $2 \times 2$ matrices and not an arrangement like a direct sum of matrices.

Comment: To have a direct product you need the two factors to intersect trivially.

Comment: `DirectProduct` in GAP will create the (external) direct product as a new group, in a representation of the algorithm's choosing. Even if both groups are subgrouyps of the same larger group, the result of `DirectProduct` is unlikely to lie in this same larger group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group $\operatorname{GL}_2(3)$ has no subgroup isomorphic to $C_2 \times D_8$. If you take the normal $C_2$ copy, you won't find any $D_8$ copies intersecting it trivially. E.g.

```
gap> gl:=GL(2,3);
GL(2,3)
gap> List(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(gl),Representative),x->StructureDescription(x));
[ "1", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C2 x C2", "S3", "S3", "C6", "Q8", "D8", "C8", "D12", "QD16", "SL(2,3)", "GL(2,3)" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right the intersection it is not trivial, I get $\{e,-e\}$. Please tell me if I am correct, but I am not able to make the semidirect product either, right?

Comment: No, for the same reason. The central $C_2$ is contained in every $D_8$.